# Detect a Symmetric polynomial

Tags: code-golf, math, abstract-algebra, polynomials

A symmetric polynomial is a polynomial which is unchanged under permutation of its variables.

In other words, a polynomial `f(x,y)` is symmetric if and only if `f(x,y) = f(y,x)`; a polynomial `g(x,y,z)` is symmetric iff `g(x,y,z) = g(x,z,y) = g(y,x,z) = etc`.

For example, `x^2+2xy+y^2`, `xy` and `x^3+x^2y+xy^2+y^3` are symmetric polynomials, where `2x+y` and `x^2+y` are not.

---

## The challenge

You will be given a polynomial, and your program should output truthy/falsy values, depending on if the given polynomial is a symmetric polynomial.

The input format is allowed in two ways. A string, and an array, like `["x^2","2xy","y^2"]`, where the polynomial is the sum of each elements.

---

## Example

```
x^2+2xy+y^2 => true
xy => true
xy+yz+xz-3xyz => true
(x+y)(x-y) => false
2x+y => false
x^2+y => false
x+2y+3 => false
```

---

## Specs

The operation has orders, just like in normal math. the order is like this:

```
() => ^ => * => +-
```

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

All the characters in the alphabet (`a~z`) are accepted as variables, everything else are numbers.

The given polynomial will have 2 or more variables.

Multiplication does not require the * operator, You only need to detect juxtaposition. (detecting by juxtaposition is not neccessary, use the better option)

Comment: Is a function a valid input?

Comment: @Pavel Write the input format on your answer and I'll consider if it's valid.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that, due to [Richardson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem), this problem is undecidable.

Comment: @Mego Mathematica would like to disagree.

Comment: @Mego Of course it's decidable; you can expand each permutation to a sum of terms of the form a^n1 b^n2 c^n3 etc.

Comment: Please specify the allowed inputs exactly and include test cases that cover the space well.

Comment: I don´t think its fair to ask someone to spend time writing an answer and then you decide if it´s valid. So I agree with @xnor. Also you indicated `() => ^ => */ => +-` but your examples do not show all these. I would have imagined we could expect `-` but not `/`. As you have mentioned `()` are we expected to handle in the format `(-1+x)(-y-3)`?

Comment: `/` is not a valid operation for polynomials, unless applied on constants. Similarly, `^` can only be used to raised variables to integer powers.

Comment: Edited! Now you might be easier to golf!

Comment: Will there ever be a negative sign in the input? For the array format, I assume you mean something like `'+'.join(inputlist)`, so for a negative one item will start with `-`, making `x^2+-x+1`?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Yes.

Comment: This is still unclear. Can arbitrary degree polynomials be multiplied? Can operations be done to exponents? Where can minus signs appear?

Comment: What's the allowed syntax for variables? Also, how do we figure out which variables are involved? `2x+y` is symmetrical if you exchange `w` and `z`!

Comment: Example `(x+y)(x-y) => true` seems wrong to me

Comment: @Leo Thanks! Didn't see that.

Comment: @ais513 I said two of the given variables. Where the variables are all the alphabetic letters given in the polynomial

Comment: "*The input format is allowed in two ways*" but they give two *very* different challenges, and a lot of the "spec" section is irrelevant if the second one if chosen.

Comment: Your comments allowing functions as input contradicts the spec. Also, one of the answers uses `*` for multiplication, which seems to be forbidden by the spec, but you haven't left a comment on that answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Maxima, 40 bytes

```
f(p):=listp(tpartpol(p,showratvars(p)));
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/maxima#@5@mUaBpZZuTWVxSoFFSkFhUUpCfo1GgU5yRX16UWFKWWFQMVKCpaf2/oCgzr0QjTaNCq1K7UqtKu0KrStdYC8jTqgJKc8GltY2ACoxBOgA)

A function that takes a polynomial as input and returns true if it is symmetric  else returns false

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, 43 bytes

```
Last@SymmetricReduction[#,Variables@#]===0&
```

Unnamed function taking as input a polynomial in the given format (except that juxtaposed variables must be separated by a space) and returning `True` or `False`. `Variables@#` detects the variables appearing in the input (and thus the input can contain all kinds of weird variable names, not just single letters). `SymmetricReduction` returns an ordered pair of polynomials, where the first one is symmetric and the two sum to the original polynomial; therefore we can detect whether the input is symmetric by seeing whether the second polynomial is identically `0`.

Comment: According to OP, you take input as a function, which could maybe let you golf that more.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 46 bytes

Basically, how this works is the polynomial is entered into a (two-byte) variable type that is dynamically evaluated. Then, we swap the X and Y values enough times to see if the function is symmetric.

```
Prompt u
For(I,0,8
rand->X
Ans->W
rand->Y
u->Z
Y->X
W->Y
If u=W
End
Ans=9
```

Comment: I know the spec is shaky, so: this program takes input as a string, works with either juxtaposition or the `*` operator, and outputs `1` for true and `0` for false.

Comment: Sure, that should be enough to detect one.